# webView.getMeasuredWidth() and getMeasuredHeight() not work on API before 4.4.X

Tags: android, webview

i have this code for my WebView

```
public static void loadHtml (final Context ctx) {

    final WebView webView = new WebView(ctx);

    //runnable and 2s delay is set because i load some javascript in onPageFinished
    //i omitted it for semplicity
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            //call some javascript in webView ...

            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    webView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                            MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                    webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    webView.buildDrawingCache();

                    //take webview screenshot loaded with a pdf/html
                    takeScreenShot(ctx, webView);

                }

            }, 2000);
    }

    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + folder + "/index.html");

}


public static void takeScreenShot(Context ctx, WebView webView){

    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getMeasuredWidth(), //<-- WHERE IT BREAKS
            webView.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas bigcanvas = new Canvas(bm);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int iHeight = bm.getHeight();

    bigcanvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, iHeight, paint);
    webView.draw(bigcanvas);

    if (bm != null) {
        try {
            OutputStream fOut = null;
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(imageTemp);
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
            bm.recycle();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When i run this code on a Samsung Galaxy tab 10.1 with Android 4.4.2 everything works fine, but when i run it in an Asus Transformer with Android 4.2.1 webView.getMeasuredWidth() and webView.getMeasuredHeight() return 0 and an Exception is thrown: "width and height must be > 0"

i read a lot of topics about this problem on SO, but everythin i tried didn't solve my problem. i wish to provide my app to API 17 customers too, and not only starting from 19...

Someone with a solution? thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be no solutions with WebView lower than 4.4.X

The only thing which worked for me is to place an hidden WebView in the XML layout, and in loadHtml method i'm checking the Android Version

Example Code:

```
final WebView webView;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    webView = new WebView(ctx);
else {
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.hidden_webview);
    webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

and in the second case, i remove this code from the inner run method

```
webView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                        MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
webView.buildDrawingCache();
```

Hope could help someone, sorry for late answer